# Creating 2D Matrix from Vector

Tags: matlab

I currently have a vector called assignments (ex. `[1, 1, 3, 2]`) of size `NUM_PATCHES`. I want to create a 2D matrix `feat_vecs` of dimensions `[NUM_CLUSTERS, NUM_PATCHES]` such that the matrix looks like this:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0
 0, 0, 0, 1
 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Therefore, if we have `assignments(i)`, I want the corresponding column `i` and row `assignments(i)` to have a value of `1`.

I am currently accomplishing this using this code:

```
feat_vecs = full(sparse(assignments, 1:NUM_PATCHES, ones(NUM_PATCHES, 1), NUM_CLUSTERS, NUM_PATCHES));
```

i have also tried using sub2ind using this code:

```
feat_vecs = zeros(NUM_CLUSTERS, NUM_PATCHES); 
feat_vecs(sub2ind([NUM_CLUSTERS, NUM_PATCHES], assignments, 1:NUM_PATCHES)) = 1;
```

However, this second piece of code seems to be a bit slower.

```
>> tic; 
>> feat_vecs = full(sparse(assignments, 1:NUM_PATCHES, ones(NUM_PATCHES, 1), NUM_CLUSTERS, NUM_PATCHES)); 
>> toc;

Elapsed time is 0.011319 seconds.

>> tic; 
>> feat_vecs = zeros(NUM_CLUSTERS, NUM_PATCHES);     
>> feat_vecs(sub2ind([NUM_CLUSTERS, NUM_PATCHES], assignments', 1:NUM_PATCHES)) = 1; 
>> toc;

Elapsed time is 0.014425 seconds.
```

I am running this piece of code thousands of times, so a small difference in runtime can quickly add up. I am wondering if there is a faster or more efficient way to accomplish this task.

Comment: you should use [`timeit`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) instead of `tic/toc`. If you really want to use `tic/toc`, at least you have to run your code many many time within `tic` and `toc` for the numbers to be significant.

Comment: For me, first one would be my best choice, it's pretty fast. `full` may take some time either way, so you may save some time with keeping the sparse mask as much as possible.

Comment: If you want to leave working in the sparse environment, definitely the first one.  I'm not sure what end goal you're trying to achieve with the above code though... so I'm not sure `full` is required for your purposes.  The conversion from `sparse` to `full` can take a bit of time for larger sized matrices.

Comment: @rayryeng I just ran my code without the conversion to the full matrix, and it definitely runs faster. I was originally concerned in my original code that it would run slower with sparse matrices, but it seems that is not the case. I'll stick with the first one, and thank you.

Comment: @It'sMagic - No problem at all.   I'm debating whether to write this as an answer or leave it... what I mentioned doesn't really qualify as an answer, but it did help you lead to choosing which method you want to stick with.

Comment: Ah, but did you try the `feat_vecs(NUM_CLUSTERS, NUM_PATCHES) = 0;` trick? I would definitely like to see some timings on, say, 1000 iterations of each one.